# No timeout for python-rq job

Tags: python-3.x, redis, queue, python-rq

Is there a way to specify a "maximum" = inf timeout for a worker? 
I have some long-running tasks and if something fails due to timeouts I handle it internally within the worker.

Can a specify this through the cli?

Answer (score 2):

timeout argument specifies the maximum runtime of the task before it's considered 'lost'. Can be used with @job, Queue, enqueue & enqueue_call.

```
from rq.decorators import job

@job('low', connection=my_redis_conn, timeout=600)
def long_running_task(x, y):
    # Code
```

[python-rq.org/docs](http://python-rq.org/docs/)

Comment: This does not answer the question of no timeout.

Comment: I thought it was for specifying a timeout. Oh wait, it is! :D

Answer (score 2):

Setting `Queue(default_timeout=-1)` will do the trick. Here is a reference to their source code:

```
    def create_job(self, func, args=None, kwargs=None, timeout=None,
               result_ttl=None, ttl=None, failure_ttl=None,
               description=None, depends_on=None, job_id=None,
               meta=None, status=JobStatus.QUEUED, retry=None):
    """Creates a job based on parameters given."""
    timeout = parse_timeout(timeout)

    if timeout is None:
        timeout = self._default_timeout
    elif timeout == 0:
        raise ValueError('0 timeout is not allowed. Use -1 for infinite timeout')
```